# Организация поиска в listview

Tags: java, android, поиск

Сделал поиск в listview по примеру, как можно убрать регистровазависимость при поиске, то есть чтобы с маленькой буквы тоже можно было искать.

```
String[] items;
    ArrayList<String> listItems;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    ListView listView;
    EditText editText;
    String textPos0, textPos1,textPos3;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(layout.fragment_search, container, false);
        getActivity().setTitle(R.string.fr2);
        listView=(ListView) rootView.findViewById(id.lst);
        editText=(EditText) rootView.findViewById(id.txtsearch);
        initList();
        editText.clearFocus();
        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if(s.toString().equals("")){
                    // Обновление listview
                    initList();
                } else {
                    // выполнение поиска
                    searchItem(s.toString());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(),
                        InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
                FragmentTransaction tr = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                String currPos = listItems.get(position);
                if (currPos.equals(textPos0)) {
                    //Создание нового фрагмента и транзакции
                    Fragment Stay1 = new Stay1();
                    // Замените все, что есть в представлении fragment_container, этим фрагментом,
                    //И добавьте транзакцию в задний стек
                    tr.replace(R.id.container, Stay1);
                    tr.addToBackStack(null);
                    //Завершить транзакцию
                    tr.commit();
                }
                    else if (currPos.equals(textPos1)) {
                    Fragment Stay2 = new Stay2();
                    tr.replace(R.id.container, Stay2);
                    tr.addToBackStack(null);
                    tr.commit();
                } else if (currPos.equals(textPos3)){
                    Fragment Stay3 = new Stay3();
                    tr.replace(R.id.container, Stay3);
                    tr.addToBackStack(null);
                    tr.commit();
                }
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }


    public void searchItem(String textToSearch){
        for(String item:items){
            if(!item.contains(textToSearch)){
                listItems.remove(item);
            }
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    //передача результатов поиска в listview
    public void initList(){
        String [] arr1;
        arr1 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.stops);
       //Arrays.sort(arr1);
        items=arr1;
        listItems=new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(items));
        adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), layout.list_item, id.txtitem, listItems);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        textPos0 = listItems.get(0);
        textPos1 = listItems.get(1);
        textPos3 = listItems.get(9);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void searchItem(String textToSearch){
    textToSearch = textToSearch.toLowerCase();
    for(String item:items){
        if(!item.toLowerCase().contains(textToSearch)){
            listItems.remove(item);
        }
    }
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Попробуйте так